# How to prove the inductive step in coq?

Tags: coq, induction

Coq beginner here, I recently went by myself through the first 7 chapters of "*[Logical Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/index.html)*".

I am trying to create a proof by induction in Coq of
`∀ n>= 3, 2n+1 < 2^n`.

I start with `destruct` removing the false hypotheses until reaching *n=3*.
Then, I do induction on *n*, the case for *n=3* is trivial but, **how can I prove the inductive step??**

I can see the goal holds. I can prove it by case analysis using `destruct` but, haven't been able to show it in a general form.

[The functions I'm using are from "*Logical Foundations*" and can be seen here](https://x80.org/collacoq/ekoyayavum.coq).

My proof so far:

```
(* n>=3, 2n+1 < 2^n *)
Theorem two_n_plus_one_leq_three_lt_wo_pow_n : forall n:nat,
    (blt_nat (two_n_plus_one n) (exp 2 n)) = true
       -> (bge_nat n 3) = true.   
Proof.
  intros n.
  destruct n.
  (* n = 0 *)
  compute.
  intros H.
  inversion H.

  destruct n.
  (* n = 1 *)
  compute.
  intros H.
  inversion H.  

  destruct n.
  (* n = 2 *)
  compute.
  intros H.
  inversion H.

  induction n as [ | k IHk].
  (* n = 3 *)
  - compute.
    reflexivity.
  - rewrite <- IHk.
    (* Inductive step... *)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to prove exactly. Proving `n>= 3, 2n+1 < 2^n` does not make any sense. According to the Coq code, you want to prove `2n+1 < 2^n -> n >=3`. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Just thought it might be worth mentioning that you can do all those `destruct n`'s in one step if you do `intros [|[|[|n]]]`.  Then based on what you've already written, `intros [|[|[|n]]]; try (compute; intro H; inversion H).` should be able to create and then immediately clear the `n=0,1,2` cases.

Answer (score 1):

The important part missing was making the inductive hypothesis general.
I was able to complete the proof using `generalize dependent k.`.

So the proof looks like this:

```
(* n ≥ 3, 2n + 1 < 2^n *)
Theorem two_n_plus_one_leq_three_lt_wo_pow_n : forall n:nat,
    (blt_nat (two_n_plus_one n) (exp 2 n)) = true
       -> (bge_nat n 3) = true.
Proof.
  intros n.
  destruct n.
  (* n = 0 *)
  compute.
  intros HF. (* Discard the cases where n is not >= 3 *)
  inversion HF.

  destruct n.
  (* n = 1 *)
  compute.
  intros HF.
  inversion HF.

  destruct n.
  (* n = 2 *)
  compute.
  intros HF.
  inversion HF.

  induction n as [ | k IHk].
  (* n = 3 *)
  - compute.
    reflexivity.
  (* n+1 inductive step *)
  - generalize dependent k.
    intros.
    compute.
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Two big problems in your solution. First, as stated in my first comment, you're trying to prove `forall n, 2n+1 < 2^n -> n >= 3`, but according to your edit, what you really want to prove is `forall n, n >= 3 -> 2n+1 < 2^n`. Second, assume that you really want to prove `forall n, 2n+1 < 2^n -> n >= 3`, then you don't need induction. All you have to do is to test that with `n = 0, 1, 2` the hypothesis is contradictory. In the other cases, we obviously have `n >= 3`.

Comment: @eponier Thanks for commenting and looking at the proof. **1)** This is a proof of _For all integers n ≥ 3, 2n + 1 < 2^n._ I think this translates in coq to `forall n, 2n+1 < 2^n -> n >= 3`. **2)**  Induction is required for this exercise, it comes from proposition 5.3.2 of "Discrete Mathematics with Applications" by Susanna S. Epp

Comment: I don't get how you read `forall n, 2n+1 < 2^n -> n >= 3`. As usual, this means: "forall n, if 2n+1 < 2^n, then n >= 3" and this is *not* what you want to prove. Surely you need induction for the initial problem, but not for this one.

Comment: @eponier is correct.  If you are proving the English statement, *For all integers n >= 3, 2 n + 1 < 2^n*, the correct Coq translation is `forall n, n >= 3 -> 2*n+1 < 2^n`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as this is homework I cannot help you a lot. Just let me write down the lemma you pose in math-comp, which already allows for the use of a sane notation:

```
Theorem two_n_plus_one_leq_three_lt_wo_pow_n n :
  2*n.+1 < 2^n -> 3 <= n.
```

Comment: I tried using Ssreflect but since I'm not familiar with it yet, I decided to rewrite in the _manual_ less natural notation.

Thank you anyway @ejgallego